# How to append to specific lines in a flat file using shell script

Tags: shell

I have a flat file that contains something like this:

```
11|30646|654387|020751520

11|23861|876521|018277154

11|30645|765418|016658304
```

Using shell script, I would like to append a string to certain lines in this file, if those lines contain a specific string.

For example, in the above file, for lines containing 23861, I would like to append a string "Processed" at the end, so that the file becomes:

```
11|30646|654387|020751520

11|23861|876521|018277154|Processed

11|30645|765418|016658304
```

I could use sed to append the string to all lines in the file, but how do I do it for specific lines ?

Answer (score 3):

I'd do it this way

```
sed '/\|23861\|/{s/$/|Something/;}' file
```

This is similar to Marcelo's answer but doesn't require extended expressions and is, I think, a little cleaner.

First, match lines having `23861` between pipes

```
/\|23861\|/
```

Then, on those lines, replace the end-of-line with the string `|Something`

```
{s/$/|Something/;}
```

If you want to do more than one of these you could simply list them

```
sed '/\|23861\|/{s/$/|Something/;};/\|30645\|/{s/$/|SomethingElse/;}' file
```

Comment: This is indeed cleaner.However,I was ideally trying to modify inline inside the same file, without having to redirect the output into a different file (or back to the same file). sed -i doesn't seem to work on my AIX box. If there is no other option to do an inline replacement, I shall go with your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @AKS: IF AIX's `sed` does not support `-i`, can you install `gsed`? Or maybe it's already installed?

Comment: @Sorpigal: Agreed. I was trying to figure out how to address a line by regex. The man page was no help.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following awk-script:

```
$ awk '/23861/ { $0=$0 "|Processed" } {print}' input
11|30646|654387|020751520

11|23861|876521|018277154|Processed

11|30645|765418|016658304
```

or, using `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/\(.*23861.*$\)/\1|Processed/' input
11|30646|654387|020751520

11|23861|876521|018277154|Processed

11|30645|765418|016658304
```

Comment: or `awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS="|"} /23861/ {$(NF+1) = "Processed"} {print}'`

Answer (score 1):

Use the substitution command:

```
sed -i~ -E 's/(\|23861\|.*)/\1|Processed/' flat.file
```

(Note: the `-i~` performs the substitution in-place. Just leave it out if you don't want to modify the original file.)

Comment: Thanks. In-line substitution is exactly what I'm looking for, but sed -i doesn't seem to be work on my AIX box. It gives: sed: Not a recognized flag: i
Usage:  sed [-n] [-u] Script [File ...]
        sed [-n] [-u] [-e Script] ... [-f Script_file] ... [File ...]
Maybe this isn't supported on AIX

Comment: sed -i doesn't really do anything in-place anyway; it just disguises a process of writing output to a temporary file which it then moves over the original, which is easily done by hand.

Comment: @flabdablet: Who cares about the mechanics? `sed -i~ ... abc` is way more convenient — not to mention less error-prone — than `sed ... abc > .abc.tmp && mv abc abc~ && mv .abc.tmp abc`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the shell

```
while read -r line
do
  case "$line" in
   *23681*) line="$line|Processed";;
  esac
  echo "$line"
done < file > tempo && mv tempo file
```

Answer (score 0):

sed is just a stream version of [ed](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/edit-ed), which has a similar command set but was designed to edit files in place (allegedly interactively, but you wouldn't want to use it that way unless all you had was one of [these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASR-33_Teletype)). Something like

```
field_2_value=23861
appended_text='|processed'
line_match_regex="^[^|]*|$field_2_value|"
ed "$file" <<EOF
g/$line_match_regex/s/$/$appended_text/
wq
EOF
```

should get you there.

Note that the **$** in ...**/s/$/**... is *not* expanded by the shell, as are **$line_match_regex** and **$appended_text**, because there's no such thing as **$/** - instead it's passed through as-is to **ed**, which interprets it as text to substitute (**$** being regex-speak for "end of line").

The syntax to do the same job in sed, should you ever want to do this to a stream rather than a file in place, is very similar except that you don't need the leading g before the regex address:

```
sed -e "/$line_match_regex/s/$/$appended_text/" "$input_file" >"$output_file"
```

You need to be sure that the values you put in **field_2_value** and **appended_text** never contain slashes, because ed's **g** and **s** commands use those for delimiters.

If they might do, and you're using bash or some other shell that allows **${name//search/replace}** parameter expansion syntax, you could fix them up on the fly by substituting **\/** for every **/** during expansion of those variables. Because bash also uses **/** as a substitution delimiter and also uses **\** as a character escape, this ends up looking horrible:

```
appended_text='|n/a'
ed "$file" <<EOF
g/${line_match_regex//\//\\/}/s/$/${appended_text//\//\\/}/
wq
EOF
```

but it does work. Nnote that both **ed** and **sed** require a trailing **/** after the replacement text in **s/search/replace/** while bash's **${name//search/replace}** syntax doesn't.